# How/Where to appropriately call controller create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just sorted out my inter-model relations regarding has_many :through and belongs_to; I also added the required id fields to the database table using a migration.

My question is: after user clicks on the link:

```
<%= link_to "subscribe", new_subscription_path(feed_url: @feed.feed_url)%>
```

I do this in my new method:

```
def new
    feed_url = params[:feed_url]
    @subscription = Subscription.new

    redirect_to reader_url, notice: "You are now subscribed to: "+Feed.find_by_feed_url(feed_url).title
  end
```

I just can't figure out exactly how and where I should be calling my create method since I want the subscribe link to create a new row in my subscriptions table.

Also to make sure that my tables are correct here are my associations:

```
User has_many :feeds, :through => :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
```

|Users table has column: id

```
Subscription belongs_to :feed
Subscription belongs_to :user
```

|Subscriptions table has columns: id, user_id, feed_id

```
Feed has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
```

|Feeds table has column: id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just broken the whole idea of REST )

The `new` actions is made to show a user some form for filling details of the resource that is being created. Even HTTP-verb `GET` (that you can see in your log for you `new` action) says that it starts an action that should NOT modify any resource.

If you don't need any forms, you can create direct "accessor" to your `create` action. But don't make it via `link_to` since your users will be unable to click on it properly without javascript enabled. Use `button_to`:

```
button_to 'Create', resources_path(your_params)
```

And then define the creation itself inside your `create` action.

Comment: trying to get my button_to to go to create not show which seems to be the default, but thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you've got? Can you be more descriptive? You had to write something like `button_to "Create", subscriptions_path(feed_url: @feed.feed_url)`.

Comment: wow never mind, you're right I was missing the s on subscriptions_path so it wasn't routing correctly. thanks!

Comment: That's exactly that I was thinking about ) I glad that you've made your final step by yourself! The `subscription_path` (without 's') leads to a single subscription view. You had to pass `id` in it in order to work. It's good that you passed something else because otherwise you would have encountered another error that there's not POST-method (associated with create method) for subscription/some_id. And it would have been logical: you create objects on subscription`s`, not on a particular subscription. I hope it helps you to understand REST deeply!